# Can I select multiple random points from .obj file by Python and Open3D

Tags: python, object, 3d, open3d

What should I do if I want to pick up some random point from .obj file by Open3D.

I test that I can read file by

```
import open3d as o3d

print("Testing IO for textured meshes ...")
textured_mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("../pikaqiu.obj")
print(textured_mesh)
mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh()
```

but how can I choose a point from the file?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can visualize the mech by`open3d.visualization.draw_geometries_with_editing()`.
Then, after the window appears, you can select points by `Shift`+`Left Mouse Click`. If you want to deselect, then `Shift`+`Right Mouse Click`. After you are done selecting the points, press `Q` or `Esc` to close the window. `get_picked_points()` will return you indices of multiple points you selected.

```
import open3d as o3d
textured_mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("../pikaqiu.obj")
vis = o3d.visualization.draw_geometries_with_editing()
vis.create_window()
vis.add_geometry(textured_mesh)
vis.run()  # user picks points
vis.destroy_window()
vis.get_picked_points()
```

You can get the points from the array of the mesh

```
mesh_array = np.asarray(pcd.points)
points = mesh_array[vis.get_picked_points()]
```